# Activate Directory Keeps Generating Self Signed Certificates for LDAPS out of Nowhere

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016

We have setup LDAPS with a public certficate

```
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: (CA ID: 105493)
        commonName                = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
        organizationName          = Sectigo Limited
        localityName              = Salford
        stateOrProvinceName       = Greater Manchester
        countryName               = GB
    Validity
        Not Before: Sep  3 00:00:00 2019 GMT
        Not After : Sep  2 23:59:59 2021 GMT
    Subject:
        commonName                = dc-1.ad.example.com
        organizationalUnitName    = PositiveSSL
        organizationalUnitName    = Domain Control Validated
```

So it is still valid.

Today morning, we found that the LDAPS connection to the server do not work anymore:

```
# openssl s_client -connect dc-1.ad.example.com:636 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = dc-1.ad.example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = dc-1.ad.example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = dc-1.ad.example.com
```

We realized, that the AD seemed to have issued a self signed certificate

```
Certificate:
    Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        1d:00:00:00:*redacted*
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: DC = com, DC = example, DC = ad, CN = ad-DC-1-CA
    Validity
        Not Before: May 31 01:21:28 2021 GMT
        Not After : May 31 01:21:28 2022 GMT
```

To fix this, we removed the self signed certificate from the certificate storage on the active directory server.

Now, around 12 hours later, the same thing happend again and such a self signed certificate replaced the offical one:

```
        Not Before: May 31 13:40:04 2021 GMT
```

Did somebody see this phaenomena? What can be the reason?

*EDIT*

Here the official cert:

```
    X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:dc-1.ad.example.com, DNS:www.dc-1.ad.example.com
```

Here the automatically generated one:

```
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            othername:<unsupported>, DNS:dc-1.ad.example.com
```

Comment: What do you have in your Subject Alternative Names? I bet the generated cert has some SAN values that  you aren't including in your generated cert.

Comment: That looks like a CA-issued certificate. DC's enroll for a cert automatically if an Enterprise CA is available.

Comment: @Zoredache Question edited. There is some othername<unsupported> there in the generated one.